# Casperjs new page but table does not update

Tags: dynamic, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to extract the table in the following website

http://projects.wsj.com/jettracker/#a=HYA&d=BED&e=2011-01-01&m=indv&o=EMC+CORP.&p=0&s=2007-01-01&sort=d&t=N125TM,N424TM,N448TM,N67TM,N866TM&v=table

The url changes to page 2, but the same table appears in either the screenshots or the saved .doc files, regardless of the pause. On the website when you click page 2 the table automatically updates. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs');
casper.start('http://projects.wsj.com/jettracker/#a=HYA&d=BED&e=2011-01-     01&m=indv&o=EMC+CORP.&p=0&s=2007-01-01&sort=d&t=N125TM,N424TM,N448TM,N67TM,N866TM&v=table', function() {

this.capture("crap0" + ".png");
var firstRow = this.evaluate(function () {
    var elements = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//*[@id="table_results"]/table');
    return [].map.call(elements, function(element) {
        return element.innerText;
    });

});

fs.write('pook.doc', firstRow, 'w');

});

casper.then(function() {
 //Click on 1st result link
this.click({
type: 'xpath',
  path: '//*[@id="results-pagination"]/div/a[3]'
});

 // var url ='http://projects.wsj.com/jettracker/#a=HYA&d=BED&e=2011-01-01&m=indv&o=EMC+CORP.&p=1&s=2007-01-01&sort=d&t=N125TM,N424TM,N448TM,N67TM,N866TM&v=table'
//this.open(url);

this.waitFor(function check() {
    return (this.getCurrentUrl() === 'http://projects.wsj.com/jettracker/#a=HYA&d=BED&e=2011-01-01&m=indv&o=EMC+CORP.&p=1&s=2007-01-01&sort=d&t=N125TM,N424TM,N448TM,N67TM,N866TM&v=table');
    },
function then() { // step to execute when check() is ok
    this.echo('Navigated to page 2', 'INFO');
},
function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
    this.echo('Failed to navigate to page 2', 'ERROR');
});
this.capture("crap" + ".png");

this.wait(20000, function() {
    this.echo("I've waited for 20 seconds.");
});
var firstRow2 = this.evaluate(function () {
    var elements2 = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//*[@id="table_results"]/table');
    return [].map.call(elements2, function(element2) {
        return element2.innerText;
    });

});

fs.write('poop.doc', firstRow2, 'w');
});


casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close! Just remember, You must use waitFor() function only when your page context includes dynamic content. This isn't the case.

Try:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs');

casper.start('http://projects.wsj.com/jettracker/#a=HYA&d=BED&e=2011-01-01&m=indv&o=EMC+CORP.&p=0&s=2007-01-01&sort=d&t=N125TM,N424TM,N448TM,N67TM,N866TM&v=table', function() {

    this.capture("crap0" + ".png");

    var firstRow = this.evaluate(function () {
        var elements = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//*[@id="table_results"]/table');
        return [].map.call(elements, function(element) {
            return element.innerText;
        });
    });

    fs.write('pook.doc', firstRow, 'w');
});

casper.then(function() {
    //Click on 1st result link
    this.click({
        type: 'xpath',
        path: '//*[@id="results-pagination"]/div/a[3]'
    });

    casper.then(function() {

        this.capture("crap" + ".png"); 

        var firstRow2 = this.evaluate(function () {
            var elements2 = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//*[@id="table_results"]/table');
            return [].map.call(elements2, function(element2) {
                return element2.innerText;
            });

        }); 

        fs.write('poop.doc', firstRow2, 'w');
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. This has solve it.  I have been fiddling around with it for most of this week, trying to solve it. Now I can actually extract the data and move on with my research.